# Object required error when recalling path from registry to reference a folder

Tags: excel, vba

My existing userform requires a folder path to be selected, to save to. If not, then the output functionality is disabled.

Note that the select folder and output functions work.

I've set the system up to save the folder that the user has last used to the registry. I can recall it as a string from the registry. When I try to set the path string (Line: `Set WorkFolder`) to the returned folder string value as an object(?), it crashes as a 424 object required error.

I found how to get things in and out of the registry. It's getting the Set WorkFolder to accept what is being pulled from the registry that is causing me grief.

The text box is disabled and is updated once a valid file dialog selection is complete so the user knows what path is being used.

I want to populate it with registry recall value (which works) and then set the WorkFolder to the path string value removing the "nothing".

When debugging and hovering over sResult, I have the proper string in the tooltip, I just need to plug that into Set WorkFolder.

```
Private Sub BtnSelectFolder_Click()

    ' ===== FOLDER SELECTION BY USER (MANDATORY) =====

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim result As Long, errNum As Long


'-------------------------------
'Trouble section

Dim oWSH As Object
Dim sResult
Dim KeyId, Rootkey

Rootkey = "HKCU"
KeyId = "Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\MyApplication\WorkbookPath\SaveFolder"

If oWSH Is Nothing Then
    Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
End If

sResult = oWSH.RegRead(Rootkey & "\" & KeyId)

Set WorkFolder = sResult '<<<<<<<<< Why won't this work? Error 424 Object required, but path is pulled from Registry successfully

'Trouble section
'-------------------------------


'All works below

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .Title = "Choose Output Folder"
    If InStr(UCase(.InitialFileName), "SYSTEM32") Then
        .InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    End If
    result = .Show
End With

' Drop if box cancelled
If result = 0 Then Exit Sub

' Made it here; try updating the linked folder, with error handling
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkFolder = fs.GetFolder(fd.SelectedItems(1))
errNum = Err.Number: Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

If errNum <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid folder selection", _
      vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
      "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Update display textbox
TxBxFolder.Value = WorkFolder.Path

'Save path to registry
SaveSetting "MyApplication", "WorkbookPath", "SaveFolder", WorkFolder.Path

' Update the Export button
setExportEnabled

Call CheckExportIsEnabled

End Sub
```

Comment: Where & how is `WorkFolder` defined?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that.... > ' =====  GLOBALS  =====
Dim WorkFolder As Folder

Comment: That has no business being a global variable.

Comment: It was an open source that I built on, it was located there. I will work to fix this as an issue...TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `WorkFolder` is declared (somewhere?) as a `String`, then a `String` is not an object in VBA - you can't `Set` it.

> ```
> Set WorkFolder = sResult
> ```

I doubt `WScript.Shell` returns an `Object` you can `Set`. If it's a `String`, then you want a simple `Let` assignment here:

```
WorkFolder = sResult '<~ implicit: Let WorkFolder = sResult
```

Different story here:

> ```
> Set WorkFolder = fs.GetFolder(fd.SelectedItems(1))
> ```

Where if I had to guess I'd think `fs` is a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` (where is that declared & assigned, and why is it not in sight where it's used?), whose `GetFolder` method *does* return a `Scrpiting.Folder` object reference.

You are reusing variables, giving them different meanings and responsibilities: that's how bugs happen.

One variable, one purpose.

Comment: Understood, I'll rework the variable names on that moto...and probably should have from the git go. I'll continue to work to see if I can sort this out...